# Variation of parameters for a linear second order nonhomogeneous equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm using variation of parameters for this problem, and I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

The question is

Find a function $v_1$ and $v_2$ such that $v_1(x)e^x+v_2(x)e^{2x}$ is a solution of $y''-3y'+2y=4x+4$ and 
$v_1(x)y_1(x)=v_2(x)y_2(x)$

$y''-3y'+2y=4x+4$

First we need to find the roots.

$r^2-3r+2=0$

$(r-1)(r-2)=0$

$r=1$
$r=2$

So, the $Y_h$ = $c_1e^x+c_2e^{2x}$

Then we need to find the derivatives and the Wronskian. I am using Cramer's rule.
$y_1$ = $e^x$
$y_2$ = $e^{2x}$

$y'_1$ = $e^x$
$y'_2$ = $2e^{2x}$

W[$e^x$ $e^{2x}$]

W= $$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     e^x & e^{2x} \\
     e^x & 2e^{2x}
  \end{array} \right]
$$
$2e^{2x} e^x -e^xe^{2x}$ = $e^{3x}$

$W_1$= $$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     0 & e^{2x} \\
     4x-4 & 2e^{2x}
  \end{array} \right]
$$
$2e^{2x}(0)-(4x-4)e^{2x}$=$-(4x-4)e^{2x}$

$W_2$= $$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     e^x & 0 \\
     e^x & 4x-4
  \end{array} \right]$$
$(4x-4)(e^x)-(0)(e^x)$=$(4x-4)e^{x}$

$\frac{W_1}{W}$  = $\frac{-(4x-4)e^{2x}}{e^{3x}}$ =  $\frac{-(4x-4)}{e^x}$

$\frac{W_2}{W}$  = $\frac{(4x-4)e^{x}}{e^{3x}}$ = $\frac{(4x-4)}{e^{2x}}$

After I calculated the Wronskian through Cramer's Rule I have to find the anti-derivative

$\frac{W_1}{W}$ = $\frac{-(4x-4)}{e^x}$

$\int{-(4x-4)}{e^x}\,dx = 4xe^{-x} + C$

$\frac{W_2}{W}$  = $\frac{(4x-4)}{e^{2x}}$

$\int {(4x-4)}{e^{-2x}}\,dx =  (1-2x)e^{-2x} + C$

The result from the anti-derivative along with
 
$y_1$ = $e^x$
$y_2$ = $e^{2x}$

should be in a formula 

$u_1y_1+u_2y_2 = 0$

$u_1y_1+u_2y_2 = 4x-4$

but I think I'm getting the letters confused. So, how do I find the values that equal to each other and satisfy this condition?

Do I solve using the method of undetermined coefficients?

EDIT: I have one more piece to this problem.

The Theorem states that If $y_1...y_n$

are linearly independent solutions of the reduced form of

$y^{n}+P_{n+1}y^{n-1}+...+p_{1}y'+p_0y=q$

then there are functions 
$v_1,...v_n$
 which satisfy 
$y_1v'_1+...+y_nv'_n=0$

I'm just a beginner at proofs. How do I tackle this problem?
 
I got it. It needed the derivatives of $v_1$ and $v_2$
 Therefore, 
$v_1(x)=4xe^{-x}$

$v'_1(x)=-4e^{-x}(x-1)$

$v_2(x)=4(-1/2x+1/4)e^{-2x}$

$v_2(x)=-(2x-1)e^{-2x}$

$v'_2(x)=4(x-1)e^{-2x}$

The problem for the theorem just needed the original $v_1(x)$ and $v_2(x)$

Something isn't right...

the answer is $v_1(x)$=$x$+$\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}$ because it needed to satisfy this situation $v_1(x)y_1(x)=v_2(x)y_2(x)$

since $v_1$ would normally represent a Wronskian in this problem, there must be something or some value...that would satisfy $v_1(x)y_1(x)=v_2(x)y_2(x)$

I've done this problem with a study buddy and we found the answer. We were supposed to take the derivatives of $Y_p$ twice and use the rules from linear equations.

My study buddy's method:

[image: buddy]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are asked to solve this using Variation of Parameters (VoP), given:

$$\tag 1 y''-3y'+2y=4x+4$$

**Step 1**

Find the homogenous solution to $(1)$, so we have:

$$\tag 2 y''-3 y'+ 2 y = 0$$

This yields:

$$y_h = c_1e^x + c_2 e^{2x}$$

**Step 2**

We are now going to make use of VoP, so we set: $y_1 = e^x$ and $y_2 = e^{2x}$ from $y_h$ and $f = 4(x+1)$ from $(1)$.

We calculate the Wronskian of $y_1$ and $y_2$, yielding $W(e^x, e^{2x}) = e^{3x}$.

Using VoP, we have:

$$u_1 = \int \dfrac{-y_2 f}{W(e^x,e^{2x})} dx = \int \dfrac{-e^{2x}~ 4(x+1)}{e^{3x}} dx = 4 e^{-x} (x+2)$$

$$u_2 = \int \dfrac{y_1 f}{W(e^x,e^{2x})} dx = \int \dfrac{e^x ~4(x+1)}{e^{3x}} dx = -e^{2x}(2x+3)$$

Now, $y_p$ is given by:

$$y_p = y_1 u_1 + y_2 u_2 = e^x(e^{-x} 4(x+2)) + e^{2x}(-e^{-2x}(2x+3)) = 4(x+2) -(2x+3) = 2x + 5$$

**Step 3**

Our final solution is given by:

$$y(x) = y_h(x) + y_p(x) = c_1e^x + c_2 e^{-2x} + 2x + 5$$

Comment: But how does that satisfy the condition of  $v_1(x)y_1(x)=v_2(x)y_2(x)$?

Edit: Nevermind. I see it...sorry about that. Thank you :D

Comment: Well we needed to calculated the Wronskian through Cramer's Rule which we did...We also got the $Y_h$. What was missing was the part when the equation needs to satisfy the condition of 
$v_1(x)y_1(x)=v_2(x)y_2(x)$
It could be that the values of $v_1(x), y_1(x), v_2(x), and y_2(x)$ must be equal to each other

Comment: Precisely, you are doing great and thank you for showing effort and your work! Regards

Comment: You're welcome. It took me half an hour just to code all of this stuff. I never knew it was hard work until now. But at least I'm getting used to the site. :)

Comment: You will get better at Mathjax/Latex and it will be a breeze as I have the same problems! Regards

Comment: Uh oh. I just realized that there's one more part to this problem. I have to find $v_1$ and $v_2$ that satisfies a theorem

Comment: Well, now you have this result and the process is clarified, have you figured it out?

Comment: blah can I edit the question to add the Theorem? I can't do it well here.

Comment: Maybe it is a new question - since you have the solution and are just verifying a theorem.

Comment: So I have to plug in the values that we got earlier and the result should go to zero?

Comment: That is just a proof of VoP (see item (3)) at http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx

Comment: So I should just write the proof down? But that theorem applies to the $y''-3y'+2y=4x-4$ equation...somehow I have to find a function $v_1$ $v_2$ that satisfies the theorem.

Comment: Review the proof and then apply it to your specific problem. Regards

Comment: I got the theorem question right, but somehow the answer for satisfying $v_1(x)y_1(x)=v_2(x)y_2(x)$ isn't right at all

Comment: What is it supposed to be?

Comment: the answer is $v_1(x)$=$x$+$\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}$ because it needed to satisfy this situation $v_1(x)y_1(x)=v_2(x)y_2(x)$

Comment: How did you find that? WHat about $v_2$?

Comment: The ebook that I'm currently using only has the solution for $v_1(x)$. I can give you the link if you want to look at it...it's on section 4.6.
And I have no idea how to get to that answer :/

Comment: As long as it is a legal download, I would take a look.

Comment: Yes it is...otherwise my class wouldn't be using it.
[Differential Equations by Bear ebook](http://scholarspace.manoa.hawaii.edu/handle/10125/21735)
It's on page 115 of the book which is page 123 on the .pdf file.

Comment: is it possible that after we find the values of $v_1$ and $v_2$ we may have to turn it into a linear equation and solve?

Comment: I am at work and will have to look at later tonight.

Comment: alright that's fine. I have to practice Calculus IV material for next week.

Comment: Indeed, I see that! :-)

Comment: @amWhy do you know how to approach this problem? :/